# Understanding confidence intervals and tests for discrete distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

Suppose one has data $x$ of a random variable $X \in Bin(n, \theta)$, and one would like to do inference on the unknown parameter $\theta$. Then, since $X$ has discrete probabilities, it makes sense that constructing a confidence interval (CI) and test with *exact* confidence grade and significance level respectively is not possible (as is also stated in my textbook...). [image] However, in the following section, when one has data $x$ of $X \in Bin(n_1, \theta_1)$ and $y$ of $Y \in Bin(n_2, \theta_2)$, the author seems to suggest that constructing CI and tests with exact confidence grade and significance level respectively is possible, when for instance doing inference on the parameter $\theta_2-\theta_1$. [image] [image] What changes when having two samples versus only having one? Why is it possible to do, for instance, exact tests?

Comment: $Y/n_2 - X/n_1$ is a discrete random variable, so the issue with "exact confidence intervals" does not go away completely, though if $n_2$ and $n_1$ are coprime then it can take take $n_1n_2+n_1+n_2$ possible values from $-1$ to $1$, rather more than $Y/n_2$ or $X/n_1$ can individually, so the question may be slightly different

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Which question are you referring to?

Comment: I was thinking of an *exact* confidence interval or hypothesis test

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the [tag:self-study] tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.